# how to fix UITextfield Anchor programmatically?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, constraints, anchor

Is there anyway to set the constraint of the anchors of `UITextfield` programmatically?

Comment: I did and it is not working the same way that uitextview works

Comment: oh ok give me a minute

Comment: I got it figured out! I used multiplier for width instead of constant and it worked

Comment: If you fixed the issue with the code you posted, you should either delete your question or post an answer below showing what you did to fix the problem.

Answer (score -2):

This is how I got it to work:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
    lazy var passwordText: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray])
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textField.attributedText = attributedText
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        textField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
        return textField
    }()

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        passwordText.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(passwordText)
        passwordText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        passwordText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,constant:200).isActive = true
        passwordText.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor,multiplier:0.5).isActive = true
        passwordText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,constant:30).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you changed from the code in your question. Please update this answer to make it clear what you fixed.

Comment: I am able to adjust the anchors of my uitextfield woth the code above ^

Comment: Of course but what did you change compared to the code in the question? Why did you remove the non-working code from the question?

Comment: I honestly cannot remember. I changed so many lines of codes around that I finally worked.